# "getaddrinfo failed..." error when accessing MySQL (5.5.17) from PHP (5.3.6-8)

Tags: php, mysql, macos

I'm a total beginner, and when attempting to connect to my first real MySQL database in the manner that most tutorials use:

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass")
```

I received the following error:

```
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I searched the internets but people only seemed to run into this problem when trying to access the contents of a remote file using fopen() or some such thing. I found their solutions to be inapplicable here. I assume it has something to do with an improper configuration?

For context, I'm running OS X and installed MySQL from the official package installer. I WAS using OS X's version of PHP (5.3.6) but in exasperation, I installed the package from http://php-osx.liip.ch/. It didn't help, but the error message was formatted much more nicely!

EDIT: I do have a workaround solution, but due to being a new user, I can't post it for 8 hours. Will post as soon as I can. Thanks!

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that [you already have an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8010567/revisions) to this issue so people don't spend too much effort on it.

Comment: You're right, thank you. You've been very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, but I don't quite know why it works. Hopefully it helps someone though:

First I had to edit php.ini to change where it was looking for MySQL's sock file ("/var/mysql/mysql.sock") to where the OS X package installer actually put it ("/tmp/mysql.sock"). This didn't work but it was probably a good thing anyway.

Then, instead of connecting to MySQL via "localhost", I tried connecting directly to that sock file. Like:

```
$connect = mysql_connect(":tmp/mysql.sock","username","pass")
```

The "localhost" is implied in the above example. It worked! I don't know why, and it seems like I shouldn't have to specify the sock file every time I want to connect, but it does work.

UPDATE: After restarting everything (Apache, mysqld, the computer itself) I no longer have to specify the sock file. I can just use "localhost." I suppose this means the problem was just that line in php.ini, but it seems like this error message should be more common if that was the case, since lots of OS X folks use that MySQL package installer. Anyways, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use only the snippet below and refresh your post with the results. The error that you're getting seems odd and should not happen with just a mysql connect.

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem. I discovered that I had a trailing slash on localhost, which presumably PHP interpreted as a socket address.

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost/', 'user', 'pass'); //bad
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass'); //good :)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I misspelled a word 'localhost' here:

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root',' ', 'mydb');
```